# How do I access a UIViewController's button from a UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I know there are similar questions out there, but please consider mine before writing it off as a duplicate.

I have a true/false that the View Controller receives from user input and uses to adjust the selected state of a button, then passes the true/false data to a UIView where a method is run. Once the method is done I would like to return the selected state of the button back to NO, however when I try to tell the UIView to access the ViewControllers button I run into some problems.

Could someone please tell me how I might do this and, if it's not possible, could you outline where I have strayed from the MVC pattern and how I might get back on track?

Comment: In short, are you looking to send a message from a UIView back to it's parent UIViewController?

Comment: If you know there are duplicate questions out there, why are you asking the question? After reading the answers to the dupes, what do you still not understand? Please be specific.

Comment: I'm looking to change the selected state of a button owned by the view controller. And I asked this question because I'm not sure how other answers apply to my question specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an NSNotification. Easier to get your head around than delegation if this is all new to you.

register something like this in your parent view controller:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodToChangeButtonState) name:@"changeButtonState" object:nil];
```

and call it at the appropriate time from your child viewcontroller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"changeButtonState" object:nil];
```

Your methodToChangeButtonState will fire when the notification is posted updating your button state.

Comment: remember to unregister when no longer required and set to nil etc (glad it helped)

Comment: I search for same thing! i used notification! its working for me!